# QueryString in a QueryString

Tags: html, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I would like to do something like below:

```
<form action=www.domain.com?retURL=www.domain2.com?parameter=a method="POST">
```

but this is not possible.

The reason why I want to do is that I have a contact us form. When user clicks submit to this form, it is redirected to a page (I have no control in this page - domain.com) which submits this data and then redirects it to retURL (I have control in this page). In this retURL, I want to show the data submitted.

How can I do this?

Long story short, I am doing a thank you page for SalesForce.

I really appreciate your recommendation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to URL encode the URL contained within your URL.

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: For example `<form action="www.domain.com?retURL=www.domain2.com%3Fparameter%3Da" method="POST">`

Comment: when I encode a URL such as www.domain.com?retURL=www.domain2.com%3Fparameter%3Da, the browser is unable to decode it, so the browser cannot access to www.domain2.com?parameter=a. Do you have any suggestions how to tackle with this?